# SherlockFragmentActivity throwing required callback exception

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am new to Sherlock lib. My code is as follows

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.setTitle("PROFILE");
    ActionBar.Tab frag1tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("LOGIN");
    ActionBar.Tab frag2tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("REGISTER");

    Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment_1();
    Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment_2();

    frag1tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment1));
    frag1tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment2));

    actionbar.addTab(frag1tab);
    actionbar.addTab(frag2tab);

}

class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    public Fragment fragment;

    public MyTabListener(Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

I also have tried implementing the listener directly but no luck. It is showing error as follows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity java.lang.IllegalStateException:     
Action Bar Tab must have a Callback
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are **setting tabListener to the same tab twice** i.e `frag1tab`..

```
   frag1tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment1));
    frag1tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment2));
```

It should be

```
   frag1tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment1));
    frag2tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragment2));
```